# Problem with SwiftUI programmatic navigation

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've been trying to implement programmatic navigation in my SwiftUI code, with little success. What I intend for the following code to do is to check whether the user has filled each of the text fields on-screen, and if yes, progress to the next screen. If not, to show an alert and allow the user to go back and fill the text fields back up. However, there's a roadblock—if the user fills the form completely on the first try, they may progress, but if not, they get the alert (as intended), but once they fill the form to completion again, tapping the NavigationLink does nothing, whereas it should allow the user to go to the next screen.

```swift
// this part of the code defines the validation logic
@State private var textFieldsInvalid = false
@State private var lineupIsReady = false
```

```swift
/// this is the navigation link i'm trying to fix
NavigationLink(destination: SetHomeLineup(), isActive: self.$lineupIsReady) {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Label("Submit", systemImage: "chevron.right.circle.fill")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .padding(.all, 18)
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.title)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        for name in checkIfFieldsValid {
                            if !(name.isEmpty) {
                                self.lineupIsReady = true
                            }
                            else {
                                self.textFieldsInvalid = true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

```swift
/* this is the alert modifier attached to a VStack that contains a Form 
(with its text fields) and the navigation link above. I haven't included the Form 
because it's too large and not the problem area for now. */

            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
            .alert(isPresented: $textFieldsInvalid, content: {
                Alert(title: Text("Incomplete Information"), message: Text("Please make sure that you have filled in all fields."), dismissButton: .default(Text("Back")))
```

For context, `checkIfFieldsValid` is an array that stores the names of nine players (inputted by the user into a text field and stored in a `@State private var`). I can include the code for these, and the form if necessary, but I'm fairly certain they don't play a part in the error because the code is able to read and access the user-entered names just fine.

Can anyone point to the area in my code that's causing the error? I'm a first-timer with only two weeks of code experience so any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I think I have got the Bug logically -> When the user fails to fill the text field & press the NavLink, the state of lineupIsReady becomes True. And if the user corrects all the mistakes, fills it again & press on lineupIsReady, then obviously nothing will happen because of True states maintained. So, when you give the Alert to the user after failing, you should implement lineupIsReady = false in the Alert Button. I hope this helps.

Comment: Yup, this was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you delete this line:

```
self.textFieldsInvalid = true
```

... then the `NavigationLink` will present every time as long as one of your text fields isn't empty. This is because you never set `lineupIsReady` to false.

```
for name in checkIfFieldsValid {
    if !(name.isEmpty) {
        self.lineupIsReady = true /// as long as one of the names aren't empty, you set it to true
    } else {
//        self.textFieldsInvalid = true (this line deleted for now)
    }
}
```

Even if only all your text fields were empty, except for one, `lineupIsReady` would still be set to true and your `NavigationLink` will trigger.

You can't set `lineupIsReady` from within your loop, because you need to get through all the text fields in order to determine if the entire thing is valid or not. Instead, you will need to set it *after* your loop finishes.

```
var lineupReady = true /// by default, set it to true
for name in checkIfFieldsValid {
    if name.isEmpty {
        lineupReady = false /// if just 1 text field is empty, set `lineupReady` to false
        break /// you can exit the loop now, because there's no way `lineupReady` can be set to true again
    }
}
self.lineupIsReady = lineupReady /// will trigger the NavigationLink
```

Ok, that's 1 problem down. Now what about the alert? Let's look at your old code again:

```
for name in checkIfFieldsValid {
    if !(name.isEmpty) {
        self.lineupIsReady = true
    } else {
        self.textFieldsInvalid = true /// triggers the alert
    }
}
```

The line `self.textFieldsInvalid = true` presents the alert whenever a text field is empty... which could be multiple times. The alert also interrupts the `NavigationLink`, which is why it didn't present. You should also only set this once, after the loop finishes.

```
/// add this after `self.lineupIsReady = lineupReady`
... 

if !lineupReady {
    textFieldsInvalid = true /// will trigger the alert
}
```

Full code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var textFieldsInvalid = false /// for the alert
    @State private var lineupIsReady = false /// for the NavigationLink
    @State private var checkIfFieldsValid = ["Text", "", "More text"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(checkIfFieldsValid.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    TextField("", text: $checkIfFieldsValid[index])
                        .border(Color.blue)
                }
                
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Home lineup"), isActive: self.$lineupIsReady) {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Label("Submit", systemImage: "chevron.right.circle.fill")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .padding(.all, 18)
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.title)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        var lineupReady = true /// by default, set it to true
                        for name in checkIfFieldsValid {
                            if name.isEmpty {
                                lineupReady = false /// if just 1 text field is empty, set `lineupReady` to false
                                break /// you can exit the loop now, because there's no way `lineupReady` can be set to true again
                            }
                        }
                        self.lineupIsReady = lineupReady /// will trigger the NavigationLink
                        
                        if !lineupReady {
                            textFieldsInvalid = true /// will trigger the alert
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        .alert(isPresented: $textFieldsInvalid, content: {
            Alert(title: Text("Incomplete Information"), message: Text("Please make sure that you have filled in all fields."), dismissButton: .default(Text("Back")))
        })
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Alert shows if at least 1 textfield is empty, but if all are valid, then the NavigationLink presents]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! However, I'd like to point out that `textFieldsInvalid` is used in the code to present an alert. Keeping that in mind, how would I edit my code?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll check back once in a while and let you know if it works.